# How to deploying node.js application with neutrino on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, neutrino

I worked on a simple application and I served it on heroku . I added neutrino to this project. locally with yarn it's working but now I have problem on serving it on heroku. the question is how can i install neutrino on heroku?

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "neutrino start",
    "build": "neutrino build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "neutrino-middleware-sass": "^0.0.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.1.10",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.4",
    "neutrino": "^7.3.1",
    "neutrino-preset-react": "^7.3.1"
  }
}
```

and here is the logs on heroku

```
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718248+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718349+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718449+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 start script 'neutrino start'.
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the portfolio package,
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-11-07T20:24:27.718943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     neutrino start
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719102+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs portfolio
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719372+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls portfolio
2017-11-07T20:24:27.719460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-11-07T20:24:27.722711+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-11-07T20:24:27.722863+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-11-07T20:24:27.722931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-11-07T20:24:27.785333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-07T20:24:27.797858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-07T20:24:27.800281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-07T20:24:36.861424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-11-07T20:24:39.981092+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-11-07T20:24:39.981104+00:00 app[web.1]: > portfolio@0.1.0 start /app
2017-11-07T20:24:39.981106+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-11-07T20:24:39.981105+00:00 app[web.1]: > neutrino start
2017-11-07T20:24:39.994350+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-11-07T20:24:39.987770+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: neutrino: not found
2017-11-07T20:24:40.005120+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-133-generic
2017-11-07T20:24:40.005428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-11-07T20:24:40.005665+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.12.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, if you are deploying a static web app or single page app to Heroku, you'll want to make sure your Heroku application is using the nodejs and static buildpacks. You can check which buildpacks you are using with:

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Which outputs something like:

```
❯ heroku buildpacks
=== your-app Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. https://github.com/hone/heroku-buildpack-static
```

If you don't have these buildpacks set, you can do it with:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/hone/heroku-buildpack-static
```

To configure the static site, drop a static.json file in the root of your project according to the documentation at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static. For starters, if you are building a single page app with HTML5 routing (e.g., react-router), you could start with:

```
{
  "root": "build",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Next up, you can store your development/build dependencies in `devDependencies`, and set the Heroku config to install them when it is building:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

When Heroku deploys a Node.js application (which Neutrino is), it tries to use the "start" script defined in package.json to start your app. This won't work for a statically built web app, since we actually want to just build the files and let the static buildpack serve it. To override what Heroku does, you can add a `heroku-postbuild` script to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-postbuild": "neutrino build"
}
```

That should get you going! Lastly, if you are injecting environment variables into your Neutrino app from Heroku, you'll want to make sure you re-build the app, as Heroku doesn't do this by default. This probably entails pushing an empty commit to your repo, or some other re-building mechanism.